# Automatic sql backup every month

Tags: php, mysql, composer-php, backup, symfony

I'm working on a project in symfony3 and want to have the application in production to make automatic mysql backups once month

I'm thinking of using the [Cloud Backup Bundle](https://github.com/dizda/CloudBackupBundle) but nowhere in it's info I can find how to make it do the dump automatically.

Has anyone came across this issue?

Comment: How about a `cronjob` that runs Cloud Backup Bundle each month?

Comment: I'm always using `cron` and a simple shell script for db backup. I think this is the easiest way.